# How can I refactor file names in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to refactor the name of the files in a project and automatically update all the imports, without caring about breaking something each time a file name is changed?

In the same manner as in the JetBrains' products. You change the file name and everything is automatically updated.

Comment: JetBrains products exist for a reason. Just saying :)

Comment: There is now the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tnrich.js-path-refactor however it didn't worked for me due to the issue I opened on github https://github.com/tnrich/vscode-js-path-refactor/issues/1. Will take a look when I can.

Comment: Yes, the extension seems a little bit buggy. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: Any updates for reliable file/directory name change and attached refactors..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you can. Natively on Visual Studio Code (>= v1.28) with [import path renaming](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_rename-import-path):

[image: Renaming JavaScript import path in VS Code]

Or with some extension like [Move TS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stringham.move-ts).

Comment: I saw that already. IMO not as good as in JetBrains, but close enough.
The question was made before v1.28 though, when that was not yet possible.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about editing the other answer, but it would be too much change, so I wrote a new one. New users that arrive here will not notice the difference, but for <= 1.28 you could still use the TS move extension I put in the end of the answer. I also must agree that JetBrains IDEs have very nice features.

Comment: Thank you very much. I noticed I forgot to mention; to use refactoring just click on the file path and press F2.

Comment: This does not work for python, as far as I tested :/

Comment: For other not JS-based languages you gona need a language processor or language server extension, like OmniSharp for C# ou IntelliPhense for PHP. There's one for Python but I don't remember it's name, just install it and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but the answer is just simple: No, you can't.

At least not currently. It's up to the authors of the language modes to implement such things. There is support for the occasional variable refactoring here and there… And there are some additional extensions in the JavaScript space that support method extraction and stuff, but none of them handles filename refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier with VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021):

> ### [Improved Refactor Participants UI](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b25448b8aed5398ad9d74f7e9dc0e61f81d970a4/release-notes/v1_53.md#improved-refactor-participants-ui)
>
> Extension can participant when use create, move, rename, or delete files.
> This is useful to automatically run refactorings, e.g. when renaming a Java file you also need to rename its public class.
>
> [image: Refactor Participant Preview]
>
> There is now unified UI for these participants which allows you to accept, skip, and preview additional changes an extension is making.

Answer (score 0):

Note there is now a [great extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomwhite007.rename-angular-component) that basically gives us the JetBrains functionality.

Right-click file, rename it.  The sibling files, the class name, the selector, the module that imports it, and the pages that use instances of it ALL update in a second.